Specify date filter
enter image description hereI am a beginner on power Bi developpement.
I wanna personalise the start date  in slicer filter in order  to have the start date equal to enddate-9 and end date is chosen from selection display.
I get only the last/first 10 lines as option on the slice filter as mentioned below
Can you please help me to fix this issue : get the last 9 days when i peak a date for he  end date  and thank you for your support.
Cdt,
i expect the start date will be related to end date  when we modify the end date the Start date Always equal to end date -9


enter image description here

Can you provide a little more detail on your data model, like which table is your date slicer from and which data tables is it related to? Assuming you have only one date slicer with single date selection, you will need to use a Measure to return the calculation based on that slicer with -9 days as the range.

we add the filter screen shot and we wanna when  choose 29/07/2024  the 11/07/2024 should be 29/07/2024-9

Here is a workaround.
You can duplicate the date table and use the new table to filter.
Then create a measure
MEASURE =
IF (
    MAX ( 'date'[Date] ) <= SELECTEDVALUE ( date2[Date] )
        && MAX ( 'date'[Date] )
            >= SELECTEDVALUE ( date2[Date] ) - 9,
    1,
    0
)

then add this measure to visual filter and set to 1


hello bro, please your support i get a resulat +9 days not like your result -9

pls double check if the DAX  you are using is correct. There are two date columns in the DAX.

this the dax script
MEASURE =
IF (
MAX ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) <= SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable2[Date] )
&& Max ( 'DateTable'[Date] )
>= SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable2[Date] ) - 9,
1,
0
)

could you pls provide the pbix file that you are using for testing?
